# php - Uncaught Error on any call to member function on null

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting fatal/uncaught errors while trying to use a couple of the core functions/classes from WordPress as standalones.

`E_ERROR: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function suppress_errors() on null in C:\Vip\_tmp\wp-statistics\includes\option.php:9`

Index:

```
@include 'wp-db.php';
@include 'option.php';
```

See the latest `wp-db.php` [code here.](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/wp-db.php)

option.php

```
<?php

function get_option( $option, $default = false ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $option = trim( $option );
    if ( empty( $option ) )
        return false;

    // $suppress = $wpdb->suppress_errors();
    $row = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT option_value FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name = %s LIMIT 1", $option ) );
    $wpdb->suppress_errors( $suppress );
    if ( is_object( $row ) ) {
        $value = $row->option_value;
    } else {
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/option.php */
        return apply_filters( "default_option_{$option}", $default, $option, $passed_default );
    }
}
```

Regardless of what member function from `wp-db.php` that `option.php` calls, the above error is thrown.

Comment: Using `@include` can mean that the include fails and just carries on.  I tend to use `require_once` as this will stop if the resource isn't found.

Comment: @NigelRen thanks! switched to `require_once` but still got same error

Comment: It seems the wordpress environment isn't loaded. Have you tried to include  `wp-load.php` from the main-directory?

Comment: @vstm I was trying to avoid including `wp-load.php` but it calls the `require_wp_db()` function under `/wp-includes/load.php`. That lead to the solution, which is to add `$wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST );` after the including `wp-db.php` in the index file

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to remedy this:

#### A. Load the WordPress environment

As suggested in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50899119/php-uncaught-error-on-any-call-to-member-function-on-null?noredirect=1#comment88798141_50899119) by [vstm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/855532/vstm), one option is to load the rest of WordPress, which would involve including `wp-load.php` & `wp-config.php.`

#### B. Missing `$wpdb` declaration

The missing statement to remedy the error message is included below:

**Index**

```
require_once 'sources/constants.php';
require_once 'wp-db.php';
$wpdb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
require_once 'option.php';
```

**sources/constants.php**

```
<?php
// define constants here
define('DB_HOST', 'YOUR HOST');
define('DB_USER', 'YOUR USER');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'YOUR PASSWORD');
define('DB_NAME', 'YOUR DB');
```